# Convert a 256 bit WPA2 AES - TKIP to a 64/128 bit key?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, 64-bit, encryption

I have a router that allows me the following encryption keys for the wifi:

```
WEP
WPA TKIP 256 bit
WPA AES 256 bit
WPA TKIP-AES 256 bit
```

Just yesterday I bought a wireless range extender that doesn't seems to be working because, as it says, it just supports WPA2 AES or WPA2 Mixed networks on 64 or 128 bit.

Is there any way to "convert" my 256 bit key somehow on my main router to a 64 or 128 bit key? I don't really want to switch to WEP because I know it is crackable... or did I just throw my money away?

I hope someone will help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: its not possible to perform that kind of narrowing conversion. you could theoretically up-convert a key, but not down-convert it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its really incredible that my router only allows me to choose between WEP or WPA2 256bit encryptions without allowing me to choose a middle range encryption.. Does it means I cannot really do anything else?

Comment: No version of WPA uses 64 keys.  Its always used 256-bit keys. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access))

Comment: How is it possible that my range extenders says it only supports 64 or 128 wpa2 keys?

Comment: @wired - What's the model of the range extender that you purchased?

Comment: Its a sitecom wlx2001..

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what information I could gather, you should be able to use a password that's between 8 and 16 characters long (aka 64 to 128 bits). [WPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) supports passwords ranging from 8 to 63 ascii characters (64 to 256 bits), so creating an 8 to 16 letter password *should* work for your range extender. Of course if your password is already within these parameters then all of this is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Basically 256 bit is the MAXIMUM range of encryption i can set the password right?

Comment: no, keys are always of a fixed length, but get padded (via an Oracle), so you can use a shorter passphrase. keep in mind though, the key is not entirely representative of your passphrase, just based upon it using a deterministic algorithm.

Comment: THIS DID THE TRICK! I love you slow_excellence! How can I mark your answer as the best one? Is there any way? Thanks also to everyone else who helped me on this